# Invalid request on refreshing token

Tags: outlook-restapi

On refresh Oauth 2 token I have this error:

> {u'correlation_id': u'6678c42e-6935-4f53-86e9-f00f5a31f8c2',
>   u'error': u'invalid_grant',
>   u'error_codes': [9002313],
>   u'error_description': u'AADSTS9002313: Invalid request. Request is malformed or invalid.\r\nTrace ID: db3676d4-5d5d-4104-96c9-f3fd92d01300\r\nCorrelation ID: 6678c42e-6935-4f53-86e9-f00f5a31f8c2\r\nTimestamp: 2019-06-04 10:06:54Z',
>   u'timestamp': u'2019-06-04 10:06:54Z',
>   u'trace_id': u'db3676d4-5d5d-4104-96c9-f3fd92d01300'}

What is wrong with my request?